# Inserir rolagem horizontal em gráfico de linha no MPChart Android

Tags: java, android, java-8

estou usando a biblioteca [MPChart Android (v3.0.1)](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) para desenhar gráficos no meu app Android, no entanto eu queria tornar meu gráfico rolável no **Eixo X**, este é o meu código:

```
private void loadDadosGraficoLinha() throws Exception{

    ArrayList<Peso> listaPesos = new DALPeso(ActivityHistoricoPeso.this).getListaPesos(ActivityHistoricoPeso.this);
    ArrayList<Entry> listaEntradasPesos = new ArrayList<>();
    //ArrayList<String> listaRotulosX = new ArrayList<>();
    //SimpleDateFormat objFormatoData = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    for(Peso peso: listaPesos){
        listaEntradasPesos.add(new Entry(peso.getCodigo(), peso.getPeso()));
        //listaRotulosX.add(objFormatoData.format(peso.getDataRegistro()));
    }

    LineDataSet objLineDataSet = new LineDataSet(listaEntradasPesos, "Peso (Kg)");//Iniciando dataset
    objLineDataSet.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 101, 0));//Seta a cor laranja para a linha
    objLineDataSet.setDrawFilled(true);//Preenche com uma cor o espaço abaixo das linhas
    objLineDataSet.setFillColor(Color.rgb(255, 101, 0));//Seta a cor do espaço abaixo das linhas laranja
    objLineDataSet.setCircleColor(Color.rgb(255, 101, 0));//Seta a cor dos pontos laranja

    LineData objLineData = new LineData(objLineDataSet);//Inicia um linha de valores no gráfico

    Description objDescription = new Description();//Cria um objeto de descrição
    objDescription.setText("Registros do último mês");//seta uma descrição para o gráfico

    YAxis objYAxis = graficoLinha.getAxisRight();
    objYAxis.setEnabled(false);

    graficoLinha.setDescription(objDescription);
    graficoLinha.animateY(2000);//Define uma animação de 2 segundos para o eixo Y
    graficoLinha.setHardwareAccelerationEnabled(true);//Habilita a aceleração de hardware
    graficoLinha.setScrollContainer(true);//Deveria habilitar a barra de rolagem no container mais não faz nada
    graficoLinha.setData(objLineData);//seta os dados que serão mostrados no gráfico
    graficoLinha.invalidate();//Atualiza o gráfico
}
```

O resultado desse código é esse:
[image: Gráfico em linha]

No entanto cada vez que eu insiro um novo peso ele continua espremendo os valores nesse espaço do gráfico quando na verdade a minha intenção é que ele carregue todos os registros mas deixe esses dados roláveis na horizontal sem diminuir o fator de zoom e sem espremer os pontos nesse pequeno espaço do layout

Comment: Desculpe eu não sei se entendi bem ou acho que não me expressei bem, mas a intenção é que ele carregue todos os registros mesmo, no entanto, eu quero que todos esses dados sejam roláveis na horizontal sem diminuir o fator de zoom e sem espremer os pontos nesse pequeno espaço do layout

Comment: Você disse: "queria exibir fixamente apenas 5 pontos do eixo X". São todos ou somente 5? Não esta muito claro.

Comment: Questão corrigida, eu necessito que todos os dados sejam carregados no gráfico de acordo com o filtro do spinner, ou seja, se houver mil pontos ele irá me trazer os mil registros o problema é que o MPChart adiciona esses mil registros sem criar uma rolagem e eu quero criar uma rolagem horizontal para que eu possa visualizar o resto

Comment: Depois de tentar continuamente desde ontem à noite eu consegui achar uma maneira de resolver meu problema, bastou inserir a seguinte linha de código: **graficoLinha.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(4f);**